# How can I update this Google Apps Script to update my Target Google Sheet anytime an update is made to the Source CSV File?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on this Google Apps Script for a while and can't seem to get the trigger right. I've tested this several times using Event Type on edit or on change and it never works when even source is the spreadsheet. However, it works perfectly when the event source is Time-Driven. I can't have it run every 10 or 15 minutes since the source file is large.

The trigger is set to:
moveAndExportData
From Event Source From spreadsheet
Event Type on Change.

```
function moveAndExportData() {
  try {
    var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1KrS69yqUP-mxHefCuVHeO8DSN90Dlt8L'); // Replace with the ID of the source folder
    var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1WHX3HZL5X_BM3vR3MM3Uv3pixhbH8iLh'); // Replace with the ID of the target folder
    var csvFile = sourceFolder.getFilesByName('Students.csv').next();
    var csvBlob = csvFile.getBlob();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvBlob.getDataAsString());

// Filter the data to include only rows where column K is not empty
var filteredData = csvData.filter(function(row) {
  var columnKValue = row[10]; // Assuming column K is the 11th column (zero-based index)
  return columnKValue !== "";
});


    var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1xH4M93X-3D8R2YEQdH_gVxUYlpN5NSGsY9EWGOyCKeY'); // Replace with the ID of the target Google Sheet
    var sheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Students'); // Replace with the name of the target sheet

    sheet.clear(); // Clear the target sheet
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData); // Write the filtered data to the target sheet

    // Move the filtered CSV data to the target folder
    var newCsvBlob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.parseCsv(filteredData.join("\n")), MimeType.CSV, 'Students.csv');
    targetFolder.createFile(newCsvBlob);

    Logger.log('Data moved and exported successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error: ' + error.toString());
  }
}


function onEdit(e) {
var fileName = "students.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
var fileId;



// Get the file ID of the CSV file
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
while (files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();
fileId = file.getId();
}



// Check if the fileId is found
if (fileId) {
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}



ScriptApp.newTrigger('moveAndExportData')
.forSpreadsheet(fileId)
.onEdit()
.create();
}
}
```

I'm able to run this manually and it works perfectly. It doesn't work using the Trigger fuctionality.

Comment: Did you check the execution logs?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I went to the execution logs and there hasn't been an update since yesterday. I updated the file over 10 minutes ago (it's 15kb) and the target file still hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 0):

By using a timebased trigger to look for changes in the file and sending you some sort of notification. But since you cannot use timbased triggers then there is no solution I know of.  onEdit trigger only fires on  user edits to spreadsheets.

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you for the comment. I was able to get it to work automatically using a time-based trigger. When I updated the trigger to: Event Source From spreadsheet Event Type on Change, that's when it doesn't appear to run. 

It's a CSV file so I would make an edit on my local machine to test it, upload/replace the file which would edit it and change the date in GDrive for the source CSV file, but no update on the target Google Sheet.